# How to ask if a tutor is ~welcoming~? new students

Tags: phrases, questions, letter-writing

I'm going to ask the online teacher if she is expecting new students to come and start studying with her.

What's the good way to ask her that? I'm not sure that my own option "Are you welcoming new students?" even sounds correctly to a native-speaker :)

Thank you

Comment: by _expecting_ do you mean _accepting or enrolling_? If you do mean that, then 'Are you welcoming new students?' sounds fine.

Comment: @ed86 yes, thank you, accepting is what I meant. You can add an answer so I could select it

Comment: @JannaTashina - You've answered your own question!

Comment: Normally, in the US, a tutor would be *accepting new students*, if indeed the tutor is open to enrolling more students.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you take on new students?

or

> Are you accepting new students?

or

> I wish to learn. Would you teach me?